# Why my app wont open after adding this line in my code : TextView t = findViewById(R.id.wina)"?

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

This is my codebase for a game but it won't open after adding line 4 if I don't use that line then my app works perfectly fine. and no error is thrown. it builds perfectly fine.

I'm new with android dev so I don't know much about it.

below is XML and java code for the TextView and APP respectively.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wina"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/board"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="24sp"
     />
```

.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int flag = 1; //1 means red and 0 means yellow
    int[] gameState = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};     //-1 empty , 0 yellow and 1 red
    **TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.wina);**


    String win ="";
    int[][] winningConditions = {
            {0,1,2},
            {3,4,5},
            {6,7,8},
            {0,3,6},
            {1,4,7},
            {2,5,8},
            {0,4,8},
            {2,4,6}
    };
    boolean gameActive = true;

    public boolean check(){
        for(int[] winningCondition : winningConditions){
            if(gameState[winningCondition[0]]==gameState[winningCondition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningCondition[1]]==gameState[winningCondition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningCondition[0]]!=-1){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void dropToken(View view){
        ImageView vi = (ImageView) view;
        int tag = Integer.parseInt(vi.getTag().toString());

        if(gameState[tag]==-1) {
            gameState[tag] = flag;
            vi.setY(-1500);

            if (flag == 1 && gameActive) {
                vi.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                flag = 0;

            }
            else if (flag == 0 && gameActive) {
                vi.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                flag = 1;
            }
            vi.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(400);
            if(check()){
                if(flag==1){
                   win = "yellow";
                }
                else{
                  win = "red";
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,win, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                gameActive=false;
            }
}
```

> @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> //normal code   }  }

Comment: You should call onCreate

Comment: I have actually called onCreate but I didn't include it as the code was already lengthy to post. but yes I have called onCreate. and still it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You have not drawn your XML file of MainActivity yet and you are calling a method to find your textview before actually drawing your activity. So, first you need to implement `onCreate()` method of AppCompatActivity and set it's content view using `setContentView()` and only then you initialize your `TextView` field.

Refer the below sample and make changed accordingly to your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.wina);
    }
}
```

[Read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#oncreate) about `Activity Lifecycle`